# My mouse isn't clicking! Do I have a virus?

Tags: mouse, virus

I think I've had a virus for about a month
When I try to open anything, I have to click 7 or 8 times!

I changed my mouse - the same problem

I renewed the windows - its became great
but after restant it happend again
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try another mouse? Maybe that one is on its way out. Also try another USB port or try that mouse on another PC

Comment: I tried to clean up the post a little, but I don't know what you mean by "renewed", or "restant". Is the latter restart, or resting, or something?

Answer (score 3):

The mouse is probably dying.

You could also try Start-->Control panel-->Mouse and move the **Double click speed** towards **slower**

Comment: Mouse buttons seem to fail in strange and amazing ways.  Mine right now will alternately not click, or double-click when I actually only single-clicked.  Time for a new one again!  (Historical mouse life span for me is right around 2 years per computer).